# Create app with REST API

Tags: openshift

I'am using the REST API documentation to create an application with :

```
curl -k -X POST https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domains/[Domain_ID]/applications
 --user "[UserName]:[Password]" --data "name=[AppName]&cartridge=php-5.3&scale=false"
```

but i want to add my-custum Cartridge not one from the Valid Options : nodejs-0.6; jbossas-7; python-2.6; jenkins-1.4; ruby-1.8; diy-0.1; php-5.3; perl-5.10.

```
curl -k -X POST https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domains/mydomain/applications 
--user "aa@y.com:xxx" 
--data "name=openerpdrupal&cartridge=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smarterclayton/openshift-cdk-cart/master/metadata/manifest.yml"
```

it's give me the

```
Invalid cartridge 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smarterclayton/openshift-cdk-cart/master/metadata/manifest.yml' specified."
```

Any Ideas how to fix this error or Maybe i forget a step ?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989777/invalid-cartridge-specified-with-exit-code-109/22991939

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

curl -k -X POST https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domains/jhaopenshift/applications --user "user:pass" --data "name=myapp&cartridge[url]=https://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=smarterclayton/openshift-cdk-cart&scale=false"

You need to supply the [url] after the cartridge parameter, you also need to either point to a manifest.yml file that has the Source-Url element included, or use the cartridge reflector to point to the partial github url with the format user/repo

Comment: of course i try it, and i have this error :
{"api_version":1.6,"data":null,"messages":[{"exit_code":109,"field":"cartridge","index":null,"severity":"error","text":"Invalid cartridge 'http://cdk-jhaopen.rhcloud.com/manifest/0b6cfc7330a1059362f5307ce6051495e4e99ba2' specified."}],"status":"unprocessable_entity","supported_api_versions":[1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6],"type":null,"version":"1.6"}

Comment: That url should be a github repo like this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openshift-cartridges/openshift-wildfly-cartridge/master/metadata/manifest.yml

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so should i put my cartridge in github and copy the manifest.yml URL in my curl command ?

Comment: Yes, it should follow the standard cartridge v2 format, you can look at the one I sent as an example.

Comment: That what i do and i still have the same error :
{"api_version":1.6,"data":null,"messages":[{"exit_code":109,"field":"cartridge","index":null,"severity":"error","text":"Invalid cartridge 'https://github.com/HamzaJemai/openshift-cdk/blob/master/metadata/manifest.yml' specified."}],"status":"unprocessable_entity","supported_api_versions":[1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6],"type":null,"version":"1.6"}

Comment: You need to use the "raw" link for it, not the view this code on github link, please actually look at the answer and sample link that i posted.

Comment: hi developercorey, i'am still having the cartridge invalid error just with cURL, but with the rhc create-app cdk https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HamzaJemai/openshift-cdk/master/metadata/manifest.yml it's working good any ideas ?

Comment: Also with the https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smarterclayton/openshift-cdk-cart/master/metadata/manifest.yml it's still not working : Invalid cartridge 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smarterclayton/openshift-cdk-cart/master/metadata/manifest.yml', any ideas or suggestion ? Thanks